# What is the physical meaning of the probability current density in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

How can we physically interpret the probability current density?
Also, what is the physical sense that it's value being zero. I know that this is zero for the real wavefunction but also, the real wavefunctions do not corresponds to any quantum particle.

Comment: The standard [summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current) is not adequate? For vanishing current, the probability density profile is fixed in time.